# In storyboard xib's outlets are hidden,after the commit and push of code to git-bitbucket

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, git

In my ios project,i am using bitbucket to maintain source control for my team dev's.here i am using storyboard's and in that for each xib i have added outlets labels,buttons,images and i will commit the code to bitbucket from source control--->commit next push,successfully added to bitbucket.

once my team members pull the code from bitbucket source control--->pull.

In storyboard outlets are not visible like shown in below screen,but i can see all the outlets in inspect and when you run the application.

[image]

i am having a peculiar issue in my storyboard after commit and push of code to bitbucket.

i need outlets to be visible after the pull of code from bitbucket.
please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your device layout....
Actually it makes on other layout like `wAny hAny` and now you show it on other layouts like `wCompact hRegular`....thats why the problem occurs...

Here is the visual presentation

[image]

You can enable it by checking the option in your attribute inspector[scroll down to the bottom]. Please refer to the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: ya accepted and raise points to me dude and can you provide your support online through skype